# I keep getting "default activity not found" in my android application

Tags: android

I have created an android application with a simple login page, when i try run the app though i keep getting the same error. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here? Below are my android manifest and my two activities java classes.

Main Activity (Login) -

```
package com.example.squashsademo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mTextUsername;
    EditText mTextPassword;
    Button mButtonLogin;
    TextView mTextViewRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mTextUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_username);
        mTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);
        mButtonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        mTextViewRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent RegisterIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register_Activity.class);
                startActivity(RegisterIntent);
            }
        });

        mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayerInfo.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Register Activity -

```
package com.example.squashsademo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Register_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mTextEmail;
    EditText mTextUsername;
    EditText mTextPassword;
    EditText mTextCnfPassword;
    Button mButtonRegister;
    TextView mTextViewLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_);

        mTextUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_username);
        mTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);
        mTextCnfPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_cnf_password);
        mButtonRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        mTextViewLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewLogin);
        mTextViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LoginIntent = new Intent(Register_Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(LoginIntent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Android Manifest -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.squashsademo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SquashSADemo">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Register_Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".PlayerInfo" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace

```
<action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

with

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: That got rid of the error but then the app just crashes

Comment: That's probably caused by something else, please copy in the error message.